# How do I fix slow-down with `pen-down` in NetLogo 3D?

Tags: netlogo

I've picked up on NetLogo a little while ago and was intrigued by the possibilites that this platform offers.
As a little hobby-project I wanted to make a simulation of our solar system in NetLogo 3D.
It turned out great but I have one big problem that I am not able to solve on my own.
In order to display a planets orbit around the sun I added some buttons with  the function to ask each respective planet (turtle) to pen-down and draw a line. However if I keep this "feature" on within a matter of seconds the simulation becomes noticably slower and sluggish. After 30 seconds or so it gets so laggy that even the interface becomes hard to use.
Without pen-down the simulation can run indefinitely.

Can anyone here tell me how to fix this slow-down issue?
I've checked the RAM usage and it is well below the limit I have set in the config file.

Alternatively, is there a better solution to visualize orbits?

Answer (score 1):

When I loaded the model library's 3D Flocking model and asked the turtles "pen-down" it became increasingly slow. The trails presumably increase the complexity of the 3D structure that needs to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I advised a student a few years ago who made models of our solar system and exoplanet systems in 2D and 3D. See http://resources.modelling4all.org/libraries/orbits/documentation

Note that the models are in the Behaviour Composer and the NetLogo code can be obtained by clicking on the Download tab.

Comment: thank you, apart from the added plotting my model is pretty similar in design.
However I've noticed that the model you showed me has the exact same problem that mine has. Those trails that visualize the orbits slow down the simulation after a couple of seconds. 
I'd really wish there was a solution for this.